# Lightning Experience - detect return url

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience

I'm trying to integrate a Custom VisualForce Page in Lightning experience and I'm facing some issues with navigation. My question is how can I detect where the user accesses my custom page from? For example:

I'm overriding the Account's Edit button so when I want to edit an Account I use my custom VF page for that. But I can access the edit page from the Account's listing page and from the record's detail page. Please see the screen shot below:

1. Edit from Account's listing page:

[image]

2. Edit from the record's details page:

[image]

Does anyone knows a way I can 'tell' my controller that the user is coming from the detail page or from the object's listing page so I can use this to redirect back to the relevant page?
I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is go back to the previous page, I believe you can use Salesforce one's built in navigation.(Which if I'm not mistaken, work in Lightning experience as well)

Using:

```
sforce.one.back(true); // I should note this is a Javascript function, not Apex
```

As noted in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_apps_salesforce1_navigation_methods.htm), it is equivalent to hitting the browser's back button. And the parameter `true` in my example is optional and indicates whether you'd like the page to `refresh`.

Hope this helps!